# Laravel Environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, environment

I am very confused about the environment in Laravel 4.2. I have setup my environment folders in the `/config` folder. I then added the following:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'production' => array('my-server-name'),
    'local' => array('my-local-name')
));
```

where `my-server-name` and `my-local-name` where taken from the terminal by running `hostname`.

When I do this however, no matter where I run the code, the environment is always `production`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like your `local` hostname is wrong. make sure `local` is correct. laravel always return `production` if hostname don't match with your current machine.

Comment: Yes, you are right, so the hostname had a `.local` at the end, even though in the terminal `hostname` didn't show the `.local`. I just traced back the `detectEnvironment()` and got to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not using `detectEnvironment` correctly. In this function, **YOU** are supposed to return the environment used, based on a config file, or an external environment variable - not get the environment. If you [look at the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration), you'll see some samples on how to use `detectEnvironment` properly, with both config file, or external variable (e.g. set the environment variable `MY_LARVEL_ENV=local` at the command line, and access it using `$_SERVER['MY_LARAVEL_ENV']` inside the function, to return the proper environment.

Comment: The whole point of environment is that you define your different configuration files and set all the environments. Then Laravel is to find out where the code is running and run the proper configuration. If I were to tell it where I am running, what is the point of that? I don't want to change my files jsut when I am pushing to my production

Comment: The point is, `detectEnvironment` is where you tell it what environment you're running in, and `App::environment()` allows you to access it later, and configure different behaviors/servers/connection strings accordingly. It's still up to you to decide if you're running locally, or in production. How do you expect the application to know which is which? Think of it as an `if` clause: `if(hostname == "xyz") return "production"; else return "local";` - you still need to provide the "xyz" for this to be accurate.

Comment: The OP's code looks okay to me. The same documentation you are referring to also gives `$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array('local' => array('your-machine-name') ));` as an example. I defined my Laravel environment this way before as well so I confirm it can be done.

Comment: Your code will always return "local", just as his always returns "production". Where is the detection? You must have a definition for what's local and what's not somewhere else (in a config or `.environment` file), for this to work.

Comment: If you trace `$app->detectEnvironment()` you will get to `detectWebEnvironment()` in `Illuminate\Foundation\EnvironmentDetector` class. In there you'll see it checks whether your argument is a closure or an array. If you use closure, yes it will behave the way you mentioned (2nd example in the docs). If you put in array it will check the array values against the actual hostname (1st example in the docs) and return the key as the Laravel environment name.

Answer (score 0):

in the beginning of a project in laravel could be a really mess with the roots and all that stuff, so I recommend you to follow this tutorial!

```
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators
```

Go to the root of your project on cmd and follow the steps,once your ready, just type:

```
php artisan generate:scaffold theNameOfYourTable
```

And say yes! 
It will create you all te MVC, Seeders,Standar of your project, and some other awesome staff. ;)